# Parallelize os.lisdir() in Python

Tags: python

I have to read the filenames from a directory containing A LOT of files, I wonder if it is possible to parallelize the os.listdir() call.

I was planning on obtaining the filenames with a call similar to that

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]
```

I would create an hdf5 file listing all the filenames within the given folder but the files are subject to change over time.

Comment: you could use `threads` but it depends on your computer if increases performance or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't parallelize a single `listdir` call, and parallelizing the filtering is unlikely to be useful either due to overheads.

However, you'll probably find [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/os.html#os.scandir) useful here, since it'll avoid additional syscalls (if it can).

```
files = [f.path for f in os.scandir(directory) if f.is_file()]
```

On my Mac with a directory containing 354 entries, some of them files and some directories, using `scandir` is 6 times faster.

```
name='t_listdir' iters=100  time=0.231 iters_per_sec=433.08
name='t_scandir' iters=1000 time=0.386 iters_per_sec=2589.17
```